# MVC model CheckboxFor first item always false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let me clarify the title a bit.

I am a model which has a collection of trailers, and in turn each collection has a list of trailers.  The html looks something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i <Model.TrailerCollection.Count(); i++)
{
    ... // some html
    @for(int j = 0; j < Model.TrailerCollection[i].Trailers.Count(); j++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.TrailerCollection[i].Trailers[j].SelectedTrailer, new {data_id = Model.TrailerCollection[i].Trailers[j].TrailerTypeId}
        </div>
    }
}
```

Now this outputs the html as I require with a list of items with a checkbox next to each one, but the problem arises when I post the model back to the controller.
If I have a list of say 10 checkboxes and check them all, when the model is passed to the controller the first one is always false, even when checked, but the others are fine.
Below is the JS for clarity.

```
var data = $("#form1").seralize
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'xxxx',
    data:data,
    type:'post'
    success: function(result)
    {...}
});
```

My controller snippet

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Update(VM model)
```

I am just a little confused as to why the first one is always false.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Rendered HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8"> Trl_86_dd_1 </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input data-id="11" id="TrailerCollection_0__Trailers_0__SelectedTrailer" name="TrailerCollection[0].Trailers[0].SelectedTrailer" value="true" type="checkbox">
            <input name="TrailerCollection[0].Trailers[0].SelectedTrailer" value="false" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TrailerTypeId must be a number." id="TrailerCollection_0__Trailers_0__TrailerTypeId" name="TrailerCollection[0].Trailers[0].TrailerTypeId" value="11" type="hidden">
        <input  id="TrailerCollection_0__Trailers_0__Name" name="TrailerCollection[0].Trailers[0].Name" value="Trl_86_dd_1" type="hidden">
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">Trl_86_dd_2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input checked="checked" data-id="26" id="TrailerCollection_0__Trailers_1__SelectedTrailer" name="TrailerCollection[0].Trailers[1].SelectedTrailer" value="true" type="checkbox">
            <input name="TrailerCollection[0].Trailers[1].SelectedTrailer" value="false" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TrailerTypeId must be a number." id="TrailerCollection_0__Trailers_1__TrailerTypeId" name="TrailerCollection[0].Trailers[1].TrailerTypeId" value="26" type="hidden">
        <input id="TrailerCollection_0__Trailers_1__Name" name="TrailerCollection[0].Trailers[1].Name" value="Trl_86_dd_2" type="hidden">
    </div>
```

Comment: ...some html <-- the details here might be relevant.

Comment: Could you show the markup generated by your razor? It seems like your first checkbox is not binding. I'm interested to see what name attribute value is generated for the first checkbox.

Comment: yeah, when razor seems to behave strangely, its best to check the generated markup first

Comment: HTML added as requested

Comment: Why are you using `data: ko.toJSON(data),`? - all it needs to be is `data: data,` - its already serialized (and its `var data = $("#form1").serialize();`)

Comment: I just forgot to add it into the code posted, but well done for pointing it out

Comment: @StephenMuecke ko.toJson was the problem, I've up voted your comment, if you put it as an answer I will accept it, thanks again.